# Trying to check if an array has an empty elements or not a number

Tags: javascript, arrays

trying to check for an empty string or an element that is not a number when run a Number() over it

```
const latLong = ['1', 'g']

function findError(obj) {
    // console.log(Number(obj))

     return obj === '' || Number(obj) === NaN
    }
console.log(latLong.find(findError))
```

It seems to be catching the empty string but not the Number() part, any help will be appreciated

Comment: in JavaScript `NaN !== NaN` is true ;)

Comment: [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: oh, can you suggest a better logic? @AndTheGodsMadeLove

Comment: thanks all you, got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking Nan, you can use the inbuilt `isNaN()` function. Check the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)
.

Answer (score 0):

```
let latLong = ['1', 'g'];
latLong = latLong.filter(el => {
  return el === '' || isNaN(el);
});
```

- isNaN() is a method in javascript which is used to determine whether a particular value is a number or not.
- Above code returns if any element in the array is empty or Not a Number.